# Can vim diff use the patience algorithm?

Tags: git, vim, diff

Is there any way to set vimdiff's diff strategy to be the patience algorithm? It's built into git and seems to be much better than a normal diff.

For reference:

- [How to set patience as default git diff algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4460202/how-to-set-patience-as-default-git-diff-algorithm)
- [Where can I find the patience diff implemented?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16066288/where-can-i-find-the-patience-diff-implemented)

Comment: That's a terrific idea. I really hope we get a complete answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As of [vim 8.1.0360](https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/e828b7621cf9065a3582be0c4dd1e0e846e335bf) (Sep 2018), vim ships with [xdiff](http://www.xmailserver.org/xdiff-lib.html) (the same library that git uses for diffs), meaning patience diff is now natively supported in vim and neovim (see [neovim issue 1466](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/1466)). Add this to your vimrc:

```swift
if has("patch-8.1.0360")
  set diffopt+=internal,algorithm:patience
endif
```

A nice introduction to both the new `algorithm:patience` and `indent-heuristic` diff options can be found at [Vimways ~ The power of diff](https://vimways.org/2018/the-power-of-diff/).

Comment: Is it ironic that I found this post because I was impatient and searched for "change vimdiff algorithm"? Huh, Ms. Morrissette?

Comment: I think your example is missing the `indent-heuristic` flag.

Comment: @Luke – `indent-heuristic` is not directly related to the patience algorithm and therefore isn't in my example settings for the patience algorithm. It _is_, however, in my .vimrc 

Answer (score 8):

I made a plugin that allows this. Try my [EnhancedDiff](https://github.com/chrisbra/vim-diff-enhanced) plugin

Answer (score 3):

see `:help diff-diffexpr`: http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/diff.html#diff-diffexpr

you might be able to set it to something like

```
set diffexpr=MyDiff()
function MyDiff()
   let opt = ""
   if &diffopt =~ "iwhite"
     let opt = opt . "-w "
   endif
   silent execute "!git diff --no-index --patience " . opt . v:fname_in . " " . v:fname_new .  " > " . v:fname_out
endfunction
```

I tried this, but I did not get it to work as git outputs unified diff format, while vim expects ed style format (see doc above). You might have to transform the output of git diff, which is probably not what you want.